# Typical Amplifier Output/Input Curve

Tags: power, amplifier, transfer-function

I apologize for the extremely basic question, but I want to be sure.

Ideally, an amplifier should have a linear output power to input power relationship. However, in most amplifiers (say a class AB amplifier) this relationship can break down at points. Am I correct in saying that as you go to higher input power, the slope of the output/input function decreases rather than increases?

In other words, if we consider the two graphs below,

[image]

does a typical amplifier act more like the blue curve or the red curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either is possible.

All amplifiers will clip at some signal level. At this point, the transfer function more closely resembles the blue curve.

Some amplifiers, like Class B biased incorrectly, may distort zero crossings. At this point, the transfer function more closely resembles the red curve.